# What is the name of this pyramid game?

Tags: identify-this-game

I used to have this game, not any more. It must be at least 10-15 years old, but possibly older. I don't remember the rules, only that you had to follow a certain path with your pyramids, and that they could be stacked in a way (perhaps blocking off others?). Searching on the internet, I have found pictures of the game, however I can't seem to trace it back to a name. One of the pictures I found shows the board clearly:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is called [Pyramidis](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1252/pyramidis) (at least the dutch version). I found one last year in a thrift store. Fun little game.

To move, take a stack of pyramids of which the top color is yours and put these one by one in the next few spots, covering other pyramids. You need to get five of your eigh pyramids into your start area. Or (which is the harder option) cover all other users pyramids so they can't move and lose the game.

[image: Front]
[image: Back]

Useless trivia, the game [Ramses II](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2629/ramses-ii) uses the same pyramids.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Fun little fact indeed, I noticed it when searching on BGG, as I encountered Ramses 2 as well. Too bad querying 'pyramids' was not enough though.

Comment: I hope you find the game. There are possibly some for trade on BGG.

Comment: I will definitely take a look! Let's see if stacking the pyramids still sounds the same as in my recollection.

Comment: You could probably get away with using Icehouse pieces for this as well - those are likely to be much easier to find as they're used in many different games.